# I have 2 dropdown lists.I want to get the value id of 1st dropdown list & pass it to controller without reloading view page in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, continuous-integration

1) My ajax script

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function kccbranchselect() {
   $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   data : 'addreceiptkccbranchid='+ $('#addreceiptkccbranch').val(),
   url : 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/student/view_sub',
   success :   function(data){
   $('#addreceiptddsmember').val(data);
   }
   });
   }
   </script>
```

2) MY view page code

```
  <select onchange="kccbranchselect();" 
  name="addreceiptkccbranchid" id="category" class="form-control">
  <?php 

  foreach($groups as $row)
  { 
  echo '<option value="'.$row->course_id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
  }
  ?>
  </select>
  <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
  <?php 

  foreach($member_by_branch as $row)
  { 
  echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
  }
  ?> 
  </select>
```

3)My controller script

```
  public function view()
  {$this->load->model('student_model');
  $data['groups']=$this->student_model->get_category();
  $this->load->view('StudentRegister',$data);
  $this->load->view('StudentRegister');
  }
  public function view_sub($id){
  $this->load->model('student_model');
  $data['member_by_branch'] = $this->student_model->get_options($id);
  $this->load->view('StudentRegister', $data, true);
  }
```

Comment: TRY MY UPDATED ANSWER

Comment: What you are doing wrong is, your current view is already loaded from the same function to which you are sending ID and expecting it to show you result accordingly. Create new function in controller, get the posted value from ajax and get results from model according to ID and return it back to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the value by  $_POST

not as a argument and one more thing you have to echo your output in your controller for ajax success otherwise if you not echo anything ajax not returning

```
public function view_sub(){

 $id =  $_POST['addreceiptkccbranchid']  //like this 

$this->load->model('student_model');
$data['member_by_branch'] = $this->student_model->get_options($id);
$this->load->view('StudentRegister', $data, true);
}
```

AND YOUR AJAX DATA SHOULD BE

```
$.ajax({
...
data : { foo : 'bar', bar : 'foo' },
...
});
```

Comment: what you want do by ajax ? and what you want get from that  controller ?